# Doctrine only returns a single result from database even though it should return multple records

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a strange problem with a query in my Symfony2 project.

I have the following query:

```
        $enviroFigures = $dm->createQuery('
            SELECT efu.wasteType, efu.ewcCode, SUM(efu.totalUom) AS totalTonne, SUM(efu.co2Saving) AS totalCO2
            FROM CoreBundle:EnviroFiguresUpload efu
            WHERE efu.customerSite = :site
            AND efu.completionDate BETWEEN :start AND :end
            AND efu.completionDate != :blank
            AND efu.totalUom != :zero
            AND efu.wasteType != :blank
            ORDER BY efu.completionDate DESC'
        )->setParameters(array(
            'site' => $cs,
            'start' => $ds,
            'end' => $de,
            'blank' => '',
            'zero' => '0'
        ));

        $enviFig = $enviroFigures->getResult();
```

And with the test data I have, there are two records this query should return from the database. I've even used this SQL query to test the general query, and it has returned two rows of data as expected.

```
   SELECT waste_type AS wasteType, ewc_code AS ewcCode, SUM(total_uom) AS totalTonne, SUM(co2_saving) AS totalCO2
FROM `enviro_figures_upload
    WHERE customer_site = 'A Customer'
    AND completion_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2015-01-15'
    AND completion_date != ''
    AND total_uom != ''
    AND waste_type != ''
    GROUP BY waste_type
    ORDER BY completion_date DESC
```

This is the output

```
wasteType                           ewcCode     totalTonne  totalCO2
Dry Mixed Recycling                 20 03 01    20          2
Confidential Paper Shred service    20 01 01    75          0.84
```

However, inside the Symfony2 application only one result is returned:

```
wasteType                           ewcCode     totalTonne  totalCO2
Confidential Paper Shred service    20 01 01    75          0.84
```

I have also used a native SQL query inside Symfony2 but that returns the same result. Even removing any parameter to search with returns the one record (even though using this method, it should have displayed 100 records).

Here is the Entity file for the table in question:

```
<?php

namespace CWWA\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * EnviroFiguresUpload
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="enviro_figures_upload")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class EnviroFiguresUpload
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="account_number", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $accountNumber;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="customer_reference", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $customerReference;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="billing_customer", type="string", length=500, nullable=false)
     */
    private $billingCustomer;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="division", type="string", length=500, nullable=false)
     */
    private $division;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="customer_site", type="string", length=500, nullable=false)
     */
    private $customerSite;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="town", type="string", length=500, nullable=false)
     */
    private $town;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="postcode", type="string", length=12, nullable=false)
     */
    private $postcode;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="job_number", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $jobNumber;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="job_status", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $jobStatus;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="job_type", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $jobType;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="completion_date", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $completionDate;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="waste_type", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $wasteType;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ewc_code", type="string", length=12, nullable=true)
     */
    private $ewcCode;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="container", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $container;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="quantity", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $quantity;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="total_uom", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $totalUom;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="co2_saving", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $co2Saving;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="total_resource", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $totalResource;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="total_co2_saving", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $totalCo2Saving;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="recovery_rate", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $recoveryRate;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="disposal_method", type="string", length=120, nullable=true)
     */
    private $disposalMethod;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="waste_hierarchy", type="string", length=120, nullable=true)
     */
    private $wasteHierarchy;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="customer_order_date", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $customerOrderDate;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="job_notes", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $jobNotes;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="customer_ref_po", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $customerRefPo;

    /**
     * @var \Date
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="uploaded", type="date", nullable=false)
     */
    private $uploaded;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="processed", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $processed;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="deleted", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $deleted;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set accountNumber
     *
     * @param integer $accountNumber
     * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
     */
    public function setAccountNumber($accountNumber)
    {
        $this->accountNumber = $accountNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get accountNumber
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getAccountNumber()
    {
        return $this->accountNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Set customerReference
     *
     * @param integer $customerReference
     * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
     */
    public function setCustomerReference($customerReference)
    {
        $this->customerReference = $customerReference;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get customerReference
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getCustomerReference()
    {
        return $this->customerReference;
    }

    /**
     * Set billingCustomer
     *
     * @param string $billingCustomer
     * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
     */
    public function setBillingCustomer($billingCustomer)
    {
        $this->billingCustomer = $billingCustomer;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get billingCustomer
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBillingCustomer()
    {
        return $this->billingCustomer;
    }

    /**
     * Set division
     *
     * @param string $division
     * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
     */
    public function setDivision($division)
    {
        $this->division = $division;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get division
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDivision()
    {
        return $this->division;
    }

    /**
     * Set customerSite
     *
     * @param string $customerSite
     * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
     */
    public function setCustomerSite($customerSite)
    {
        $this->customerSite = $customerSite;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get customerSite
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCustomerSite()
    {
        return $this->customerSite;
    }

    /**
     * Set town
     *
     * @param string $town
     * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
     */
    public function setTown($town)
    {
        $this->town = $town;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get town
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTown()
    {
        return $this->town;
    }

    /**
     * Set postcode
     *
     * @param string $postcode
     * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
     */
    public function setPostcode($postcode)
    {
        $this->postcode = $postcode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get postcode
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPostcode()
    {
        return $this->postcode;
    }

    /**
     * Set jobNumber
     *
     * @param integer $jobNumber
     * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
     */
    public function setJobNumber($jobNumber)
    {
        $this->jobNumber = $jobNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get jobNumber
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getJobNumber()
    {
        return $this->jobNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Set jobStatus
     *
     * @param string $jobStatus
     * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
     */
    public function setJobStatus($jobStatus)
    {
        $this->jobStatus = $jobStatus;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get jobStatus
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getJobStatus()
    {
        return $this->jobStatus;
    }

    /**
     * Set jobType
     *
     * @param string $jobType
     * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
     */
    public function setJobType($jobType)
    {
        $this->jobType = $jobType;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get jobType
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getJobType()
    {
        return $this->jobType;
    }

    /**
     * Set completionDate
     *
     * @param string $completionDate
     * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
     */
    public function setCompletionDate($completionDate)
    {
        $this->completionDate = $completionDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get completionDate
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCompletionDate()
    {
        return $this->completionDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set wasteType
     *
     * @param string $wasteType
     * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
     */
    public function setWasteType($wasteType)
    {
        $this->wasteType = $wasteType;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get wasteType
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getWasteType()
    {
        return $this->wasteType;
    }

    /**
     * Set ewcCode
     *
     * @param string $ewcCode
     * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
     */
    public function setEwcCode($ewcCode)
    {
        $this->ewcCode = $ewcCode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ewcCode
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEwcCode()
    {
        return $this->ewcCode;
    }

    /**
     * Set container
     *
     * @param string $container
     * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
     */
    public function setContainer($container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get container
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getContainer()
    {
        return $this->container;
    }

    /**
     * Set quantity
     *
     * @param integer $quantity
     * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
     */
    public function setQuantity($quantity)
    {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get quantity
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getQuantity()
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    /**
     * Set totalUom
     *
     * @param string $totalUom
     * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
     */
    public function setTotalUom($totalUom)
    {
        $this->totalUom = $totalUom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get totalUom
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTotalUom()
    {
        return $this->totalUom;
    }

    /**
     * Set co2Saving
     *
     * @param string $co2Saving
     * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
     */
    public function setCo2Saving($co2Saving)
    {
        $this->co2Saving = $co2Saving;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get co2Saving
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCo2Saving()
    {
        return $this->co2Saving;
    }

    /**
     * Set totalResource
     *
     * @param string $totalResource
     * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
     */
    public function setTotalResource($totalResource)
    {
        $this->totalResource = $totalResource;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get totalResource
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTotalResource()
    {
        return $this->totalResource;
    }

    /**
     * Set totalCo2Saving
     *
     * @param string $totalCo2Saving
     * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
     */
    public function setTotalCo2Saving($totalCo2Saving)
    {
        $this->totalCo2Saving = $totalCo2Saving;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get totalCo2Saving
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTotalCo2Saving()
    {
        return $this->totalCo2Saving;
    }

    /**
     * Set recoveryRate
     *
     * @param string $recoveryRate
     * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
     */
    public function setRecoveryRate($recoveryRate)
    {
        $this->recoveryRate = $recoveryRate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get recoveryRate
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getRecoveryRate()
    {
        return $this->recoveryRate;
    }

    /**
     * Set disposalMethod
     *
     * @param string $disposalMethod
     * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
     */
    public function setDisposalMethod($disposalMethod)
    {
        $this->disposalMethod = $disposalMethod;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get disposalMethod
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDisposalMethod()
    {
        return $this->disposalMethod;
    }

    /**
     * Set wasteHierarchy
     *
     * @param string $wasteHierarchy
     * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
     */
    public function setWasteHierarchy($wasteHierarchy)
    {
        $this->wasteHierarchy = $wasteHierarchy;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get wasteHierarchy
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getWasteHierarchy()
    {
        return $this->wasteHierarchy;
    }

    /**
     * Set customerOrderDate
     *
     * @param string $customerOrderDate
     * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
     */
    public function setCustomerOrderDate($customerOrderDate)
    {
        $this->customerOrderDate = $customerOrderDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get customerOrderDate
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCustomerOrderDate()
    {
        return $this->customerOrderDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set jobNotes
     *
     * @param string $jobNotes
 * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
 */
public function setJobNotes($jobNotes)
{
    $this->jobNotes = $jobNotes;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get jobNotes
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getJobNotes()
{
    return $this->jobNotes;
}

/**
 * Set customerRefPo
 *
 * @param string $customerRefPo
 * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
 */
public function setCustomerRefPo($customerRefPo)
{
    $this->customerRefPo = $customerRefPo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get customerRefPo
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getCustomerRefPo()
{
    return $this->customerRefPo;
}

/**
 * Set uploaded
 *
 * @param \Date $uploaded
 * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
 */
public function setUploaded($uploaded)
{
    $this->uploaded = $uploaded;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get uploaded
 *
 * @return \Date
 */
public function getUploaded()
{
    return $this->uploaded;
}

/**
 * Set processed
 *
 * @param boolean $processed
 * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
 */
public function setProcessed($processed)
{
    $this->processed = $processed;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get processed
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getProcessed()
{
    return $this->processed;
}

/**
 * Set deleted
 *
 * @param boolean $deleted
 * @return EnviroFiguresUpload
 */
public function setDeleted($deleted)
{
    $this->deleted = $deleted;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get deleted
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getDeleted()
{
    return $this->deleted;
}
```

}

From what I've done so far, it does seem to be a Symfony2 issue as I can retrieve the data from MySQL quite easily. It just doesn't work here.

**EDIT**
I noticed that with the collation of the table, all the fields were set to `latin1_swedish_ci`. I've changed this to `utf8_unicode_ci`but this hasn't made a difference. I've also removed the blank checks in the query, again this still only returns one record.

**EDIT 2**
I've used EchoSQLLogger, and this is the output for this particular query inside Symfony2:

```
SELECT e0_.waste_type AS waste_type0, e0_.ewc_code AS ewc_code1, SUM(e0_.total_uom) AS sclr2, SUM(e0_.co2_saving) AS sclr3 FROM enviro_figures_upload e0_ WHERE e0_.customer_site = ? AND e0_.completion_date BETWEEN ? AND ? AND e0_.completion_date <> ? AND e0_.total_uom <> ? AND e0_.waste_type <> ? GROUP BY e0_.waste_type ORDER BY e0_.completion_date DESC
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(25) "CBS - Arena Park Coventry"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "2014-01-16"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "2015-01-16"
  [3]=>
  string(0) ""
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
  [5]=>
  string(0) ""
}
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  int(2)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(2)
  [3]=>
  int(2)
  [4]=>
  int(2)
  [5]=>
  int(2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are comparing with empty sting `AND total_uom != ''` in custom query where in symfony query you are comparing with  `AND efu.totalUom != :zero`.

Also `group by` statement is missing in symfony query.

Comment: I've added those missing bits and there's no difference. I've even removed the checks for empty strings and, again, it just returns the one result.